# onActivityResult requestCode returns 0

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have MainActivity with a fragment consisting of two tabs, with one fragment in each tab (ChatListFragment and FriendListFragment). Each fragment has ListView. When user tap on each row of ListView, ChatActivity will show.

I wanted ListView (with ListAdapter as adapter that calls ChatActivity) in ChatListFragment to update its ListView once ChatActivity closes. I have tried onActivityResult method as shown below in my code but requestCode is always -1.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + " " + requestCode + " == " + MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE + " and " + resultCode + " == " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + MainActivity.class.getSimpleName());

        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

ChatListFragment.java

```
public class ChatListFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + TAG);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + " " + requestCode + " == " + MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE + " and " + resultCode + " == " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
        if ((requestCode == MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)) {
            List<Friend> friendList = getFriendChatList();
            adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_list, friendList, true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult number of friend chats: " + getFriendChatList().size());
            if(friendList.isEmpty()) {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChatActivity.java

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        if (getParent() == null) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        } else {
            getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {

   private static final int MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 9000;

   public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Friend> objects, boolean isChat) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(null == view) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_friend, null);
        }

        final Friend friend = friendList.get(position);

        if(null != friend) {
            final CardView rowLayout = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout);
            final ImageView friendImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_friend_image);
            final TextView friendName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_friend_name);
            final TextView friendDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_friend_description);
            final TextView friendLastChatTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_friend_lastChatTime);

            // Open chat activity
            rowLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_FRIEND_NAME, friend.getName());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling the ChatActivity?

Comment: Added code ListAdapter for your reference :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an Intent and then set the Result to that Intent.

Try something like this in your `ChatActivity`

```
Intent intent=new Intent();

if (getParent() == null) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
        } else {
            getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
        }

      finish();
```

You also need to `finish` your ChatActivity after setting the result. Like this:

What I don't understand, is why you need to check for parent class. You can always simply do like this

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

And this should work properly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I realized smth, onActivtyResult is always called first before setResult, causing resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK :/

Comment: I did not follow...what are you trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late! But, the `onActivityResult` will not get the result which you set in `setResult()`!
Because you set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in `rowLayout.setOnClickListener`

Based on [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
>   the activity being launched.

SO, first of all, remove `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
Then `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);` in appropriate place

In this situation, you will get the response which you set, in `onActivityResult`